What is the title of movie about forbidden fruit
Movie's plot revolves around an old man living in an old fashioned house near a small garden. As I remember in the end it turned out to be Garden of Eden where The Tree of Knowledge of Good & Evil grows. Old man turns to be Devil temptating main character to snatch the fruit breaking Lord's decree. Human however shook temptation and Devil awaits for the next visitor. Last scene features pictersque landscape with a sole tree and beautiful apples.
It was american movie filmed in this century.

I believe you are looking for "The Garden" from 2006...this century 
The boy Sam is tormented by dreadful visions and nightmares and self-inflicts injures to his body. After a period in the hospital, Dr. Cairns tells Sam's father David that the boy is affected by the divorce of his parents and a period together with him would be good for Sam. David travels with Sam in his truck but Sam sees a spirit on the road and pulls the steering wheel off his father, provoking a car accident. Out of the blue, the farmer Ben Zachary rescues them and offers a job to David in his farm. He accepts the offer and enrolls Sam at the local school. Sam has Bible classes with Miss Grace Chapman and sooner he leans that Mr. Zachary is the devil and the place is the Garden of Eden. Further, Zachary has an evil plan for David. http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0436343/imdb

Oh yes, thank you very much. Mr. Zachary was portraited by a famous actor - Lance Henriksen.

Thanks for the question, I really want to see this now, I am adding it to my netflix list :)
